# The "edit" option is missing from the Ubuntu Software installer

Tags: updates, software-center, repository

This means I am unable to add or modify the repositories using the GUI.

The only options on the menu are:

- Software and Updates
- About
- Quit

I'm running the software center as a user, not as root or sudo - it asks for my password when I install something.

Clicking on "About" says the software is called Ubuntu Software version  3.20.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: searching for software & updates][image: Ubuntu 16.04 System Settings]The option for adding repositories is not in Ubuntu Software. It is in Software and Updates option in the system settings

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but  I don't have a Software and Updates section in the settings. I'd upload a screenshot, but I can't see an option for that.

Comment: Your ubuntu version

Comment: 16.04 with all security updates as of 16 June 2017.

Comment: My System only shows Details, Sharing, Universal Access and Users (Not User Accounts). The other icons are missing.

Comment: You can search for software and updates in dash

Comment: It doesn't appear. I get Software updater and Ubuntu Software when I type "Software". If I add "and Updates", nothing is shown that matches.

Comment: run `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`